# removing items from a list that are similiar

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, python-3.6

Starting with a list of tuples, that contain the x and y coordinates of points on a graph; I'd like to delete duplicate points in the list; however for my purposes points that are within a distance of 10 I consider duplicates.

I've written a function that seems to do the job, but I'm betting there is a better way. In the sample data below: points 1, 2, and 5 are duplicates (within distance of 10 of each other). I don't care which of those three points survive the elimination process. I expect to be processing no more than 100 points, with about 50% of those being eliminated. Thanks!

```
def is_close(pointA, pointB, closeness):
    x1, y1  = pointA
    x2, y2 = pointB
    distance = int(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**0.5) # distance formula
    if distance < closeness:
        return True
    return False

def remove_close_duplicated(data, closeness):
    if len(data) < 2: # can't have duplicates if there aren't at least 2 points
        return data
    new_list_points = []
    for i, point in enumerate(data):
        if i == 0:
            new_list_points.append(point)
            continue
        close = False
        for new_point in new_list_points:
            if is_close(new_point, point, closeness):
                close = True
                break 
        if close == False:
            new_list_points.append(point)
    return new_list_points

sample_data =[
    (600, 400), # 1
    (601, 401), # 2
    (725, 300), # 3
    (800, 900), # 4
    (601, 400), # 5
]

closeness = 10                  
print(remove_close_duplicated(sample_data, closeness))
'''
output is:
[(600, 400), (725, 300), (800, 900)]
'''
```

Comment: Just sort the points, and you can iterate through the list and discard any that are close to the previous point.

Comment: @HåkenLid: Sorting can help, but you can’t just consider consecutive points since no sort order will guarantee that nearby points are never separated by one that is far away.

Comment: What should be done about a long chain of points, each close to the previous one but with the last very far from the first?

Comment: @HåkenLid:sorting is good enough for what I need, thanks.

Comment: @Davis Herring: I see your point, in general sorting would be unreliable (but I think it is good enough for my purposes). For my purposes a long chain like that would need to be replaced with just one member of the chain.

Comment: Cool. @DavisHerring is correct though. But to fully solve the problem you would need to use a proper clustering algorithm. I'm not sure which one is best suited for this particular problem, but one possibility is k-means clustering.

Comment: [clustering algorithms in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this: finding the close pairs and finding the well-separated sets (the equivalence classes of the transitive closure of the near-neighbor relation, or the connected components of the near-neighbor graph).

At only 100 points, you can afford to do the first part by brute force, but the efficient choices include grouping into bins 10 on a side, such that all of a point’s near neighbors must be in its bin or an adjacent one, or storing the points in something like a *k*-*d* tree.

For the second part, one standard solution is to build a disjoint-set forest, applying the union operation between every neighboring pair (arbitrarily choosing a point to store in the (new) root).  The points associated with the roots at the end are the reduced set desired.